# require 'randomsecure' Ruby, Windows PC

Tags: ruby, require

I use an IDE called DSP Robotics Flowstone v3.0.8.1 in which I run Ruby v1.9.3. When I run the following Ruby command in the IDE, it works perfectly fine, but the moment I export the code as an `*.exe` file, the `require 'randomsecure'` instruction seems to NOT find the `randomsecure.rb` file on my Windows 10 Pro PC as it doesn't function at all:

```
require 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Dunbot Software\Unique Random Code Generators\securerandom'
output 0, SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(25,true)
```

Why does this works in the IDE, but not when exported as an `*.exe` file?

NOTE: When exported as an `*.exe`, the `*.exe` file as well as the `securerandom.rb` file are still in the exact same directory as the original `*.fsm` file that worked in the IDE.

Comment: It might be best to direct this to DSP Robotics' support, since I have an inkling that this is related to the internal workings of FlowStone which nobody else but them knows about.

Comment: it's `require 'securerandom'`, btw.

Comment: Thank you, I did contact DSP Robotics and they confirmed that the "require" command (and therefore the Ruby Gems as well) is currently not available through the Flowstone Ruby Code Editor. 

I have requested DSP Robotics for availability of the "require" command as well as the Ruby Gems through their Ruby Code Editor - it is now on their wishlist and they are working on the issue.

Their Ruby Code Editor handle many Ruby syntax differently from the usual Ruby interface syntax - as I correctly recorded above - which sometimes is a headache to get usual Ruby Code to function as expected.